# ERROR: control reached end of trigger procedure without RETURN, the function does not work

Tags: database, postgresql

```
create or replace function summ_price()
    returns trigger
    language plpgsql
as
$$
begin
    update exam_db.services
    set price = (8)
    where id = 2;
end;
$$;

create trigger price_changes
    after insert or update
    on team
    for each row
execute procedure summ_price();
```

Answer (score 0):

A trigger function must return either NULL or a record/row value having exactly the structure of the table the trigger was fired for. You need to add `RETURN NULL` in your trigger function.

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION summ_price()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
BEGIN
    UPDATE exam_db.services
    SET price = (8)
    WHERE id = 2;

    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$;
```